# How to run the ruby command?

Tags: ruby

After running

```
gem install pragmatic_segmenter
```

I want to try the application as the following guide.

```
text = "Hello world. My name is Mr. Smith. I work for the U.S. Government and I live in the U.S. I live in New York."
ps = PragmaticSegmenter::Segmenter.new(text: text)
ps.segment
```

But how to implement it with a ruby file? I am not familiar to ruby.

Comment: You have to require it. Try putting `require "pragmatic_segmenter"` on top of your ruby file.

Comment: The gem requires Ruby 2.1.5 and above. You are using 1.9.1

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest finding a guide on Ruby basics - such as running code from a file vs command line interpreters like irb or pry.

If you want to run from file make a file `your_file.rb`. Make sure to require any gem you want to use at the top of your file. In this case `require "pragmatic_segmenter"`. In your last line have `puts ps.segment` to display the output you are looking for.

*However*

I would strongly recommend installing pry.

`gem install pry`

and run it in your terminal

`pry`

Now you can type or copy/paste your ruby code and get an instant output rather than making a separate file. Making a file is only necessary if you are writing an actual program or if you need to debug.

**updated per your comment**

Paste this exactly into your .rb file:

```
require "pragmatic_segmenter"

text = "Hello world. My name is Mr. Smith. I work for the U.S. Government and I live in the U.S. I live in New York."
ps = PragmaticSegmenter::Segmenter.new(text: text)
puts ps.segment
```

Comment: Instead of pry, I just do `ruby -e "p ..."`

Comment: It seems your Ruby version does not support this gem. The gem requires Ruby 2.1.5 and above. If you do so, the code I pasted WILL work. However, in your Ruby version, the gem cannot run properly the way it is written (giving a syntax error).